# How to use source control with wso2 api manager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We are using wso2 api manager to deploy RESTful apis. The swagger definitions generated by api manager needs to be stored in source control.

Is there a way to keep swagger definition generated by api manager and source control in sync? Ideally, it should be 2 way sync i.e. if the swagger definition changes in source control it should automatically update api manager and vice versa. we are open to using any source control that supports this functionality

Even better, we would like to have complete api (swagger + end point + api specific meta data) in some version control. Currently only option is to export the api using command line tool and store the zip file in source control.

Answer (score 0):

API Manager don't keep the swagger in the file system, it is saved in database as registry enry.

All of the WSO2 products support clustering where the changes in the master node is synchronized through SVN between other worker nodes. I hope, you can use it for the above purpose.

Have a look on [Introduction to Deployment Synchronizer](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Introduction+to+Deployment+Synchronizer), all the meta file related to API, endpoints are committed to SVN repo when ever there is a change.

Comment: The reason for using source control is to to be able to tag and rollback specific api changes when needed. Do you think deployment synchronizer will allows us to rollback to specific version. BTW, we are currently using deployment synchronizer.